# JSP include, import code after and before

Tags: java, html, jsp, import, include

I have the following structure in many pages in my web app. I would like to create a template page with the fixed code before and after the page code and then put my code for each different page. The problem is that I should cut `div`s in different files.

```
<!-- fixed jsp code 
  <header>
  <imports> ...
  <div id="some-fixes-divs-inside">
-->

   page code

<!-- fixed jsp code
  </div>
  <other>
  <footer>
 -->
```

The only way I know would be something like this but I think is not a good practice to cut `div`s:

```
<jsp:include page="fixed-jsp-code-head.jsp" />
    my page code
<jsp:include page="fixed-jsp-code-footer.jsp" />
```

> Q1: Are there any directive or something in jsp or any other framework to do that?
>
> Q2: If first Q is no, is my solution a bad practice?

**Edit:** I would like to know if are there any directive like `<import>mycode</import>` to have in the template all the code footer and header and don't open the same `div` in the header and close it in the footer, and put my code inside the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Apache Tiles. It is a template composition framework. Like [this](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/concepts.html).

First of all, define a template:

```
<definition name="myapp.homepage" template="/layouts/classic.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/tiles/banner.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="menu" value="/tiles/common_menu.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/tiles/home_body.jsp" />
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/credits.jsp" />
</definition>
```

And after that use it in your code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> If first Q is no, is my solution a bad practice?

In my opinion separating jsps according to respective functionalities is a good practice. That makes your code loosely coupled. In future if you have to change the header/footer code you will only have to change it at one place, reducing a lot of rework.

> Q1: Are there any directive or something in jsp or any other framework
>   to do that?

The standard way of including a jsp in another jsp is using

`<%@include file="your jsp"/>`(static include) or

`<jsp:include page="fixed-jsp-code-footer.jsp" />` (dynamic include)

You can also use a JSTL tag

```
`<c:import url=”http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html” />` (dynamic include)
```

It works a lot like  , but it’s more powerful and flexible: unlike the other two includes, the  url can be from outside the web Container!

Comment: Thanks for response. Static include is faster than dynamic and c:import is more powerful but also heavier so I would use it only if I need it extra functionalities. But my problem is divide a DIV between two files. In the header I should open it and in the footer I should close. I would like to know if are there any directive like <import>mycode<import> to have in the template all the code footer and header.