# Dynamic content replacement while redirecting URL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

I am currently learning about web development and I am thinking about dynamically changing content on my web application. For example I have a header and side navbar in the same all the time and only the content is changing / scrolling. If I redirect from page form A to form B I want it to be replaced only in the content area, the rest of it such as header and navbar should not be changed. How can I achieve such behaviour, what are the best ways to do that?

I am using Java with SpringMVC and JSP so far, should it be done for example via `<jsp:include="url"/>`? Any hints would be useful. I rather don't want to use angular for now.

Comment: Search for "ajax examples". Using jquery makes it somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31381338/5963546)

Basically, you need a "base" or "index" file, which will have the header and side navbar (and other static information). Then, the "dynamic" information is the form content you are talking about.

When having diferent files you only need to import the file with the header and navbar and then add the dynamic information you wish.